on input event not working properly for input tag which input tag is in the summornote editor
enter image description here
this is summernote and in the summmernote editor input, but when I insert value in input tag then call on input event for fill input value attribute, now my issue is that if I type "python" then I get "pytho". the last character is not called on input event.
below is my code.
input class is "standardTextbox"
Does anyone know about this issue
$('body').on('input', '.standardTextbox', function () {
                var InValue = $(this).val();
                $(this).attr('value', InValue);
            });


Try onChange method for that, like
$(document).on('input.change', '.standardTextbox', function() {
    var InValue = $(this).val();
    // Do something with the complete value
});


I tried with input. change, but the same issue occurred.
when value is inserted, need to click out of the input box.

So I do know how it works in summernote , but if I consider jquery then this should work. And I think we need someone with summernote editor knowledge also
